# Setting an additional caller-defined context for DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, json-deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

For `BinaryFormatter` I can set an additional caller-defined context, which will be passed as parameter to the method called after deserialization, e.g. decorated with `[OnDeserialized]` attribute.
Calling the method decorated with `[OnDeserialized]` for `DataContractJsonSerializer` works, but how can I set an additional caller-defined context for it? Is it possible?
I would like to avoid to call some dedicated method like `SetBusinessObj(..)` manually after deserialization.

```
var businessObject = "some business object";
var serObj = new SerialClass(businessObject) { Data1 = "some data1" };
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter(null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Other, businessObject));
    bf.Serialize(ms, serObj);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    var deserObj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    //How to set an additional caller-defined context?
    var jsnSer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SerialClass));
    jsnSer.WriteObject(ms, serObj);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    var deserObj = jsnSer.ReadObject(ms);
}

[Serializable]
class SerialClass
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    private object _businessObj = null;
    public SerialClass(object bo)
    {
        _businessObj = bo;
    }
    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext sctx)
    {
        if(sctx.Context is string dataIsHere)
        {
            _businessObj = dataIsHere;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to pass in a specific `StreamingContext`, the code just uses a hardcoded `default(StreamingContext)`.  Proving this by reading through the source code is a bit involved, but it boils down to the constructor for [`XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.DataContractSerialization/src/System/Runtime/Serialization/Json/XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson.cs) where `default(StreamingContext)` is passed to the base class.  Should I make that an answer?

Comment: It's definitely an answer, one thing I would offer to use this [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/Json/XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson.cs,36d490852d07fb00) rather than on github.